# $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{1/x}$

Tags: limits

This question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59313/evaluating-lim-limits-x-to-01x1-x)

However, $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} (1+x)^{1/x} = \lim_{x\to 0^-} (1+x)^{1/x} = e$$

And it seems that $\lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{1/x} = 1^{undefined} = 1$

Also, I thought the limit in theory does not exist right if the left and right limits don't match the function at the value?

And when I plot it on [desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), it shows the value is undefined at $x=0$.

Can someone help clarify please?

Comment: The value is undefined at $x=0$, but the limit still exists.

Comment: Think about this function $f(x) = \frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2}$. This function is not defined at $x=2$, however, $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 4 \ne f(2)$.

Comment: It is undefined at 0.  But it is defined in the neighborhood of 0.

Comment: Also to note that $1^\infty$ is undefined and does not actually equal $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that a limit does not exist if the left and right limits don't match - but it's *each other* that they need to match, not the function. Desmos isn't telling you that the left and right limits don't match, it's telling you that the function is undefined *at that point* - which is actually completely irrelevant for limits. In fact, the whole point of talking about limits is to deal with the fact that sometimes we can't just plug things in, even though there's a value that "makes sense" there. For example, in the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$, $f$ is not defined at $x = 0$. But $f$ is "obviously" just the constant function $1$, so it "makes sense" to say that $f(0)$ is $1$. So instead of saying the false thing that $\frac{0}{0} = 1$, we use the notation $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{x} = 1$, which just means "when $x$ is close enough to $0$, $\frac{x}{x}$ is close enough to $1$".

Now, because we're worried about this sort of situation, we have to be very careful about when we plug in numbers. In particular, any situation where the *exact* value of $x$ is important is concerning - a good example is $\frac{x}{x}$. If we tried to plug in $x = 0$, we might say "well, obviously $\frac{0}{\textrm{anything}}$ is $0$, so this is $0$". But that relies on $x$ being *exactly* zero, which isn't something we get to do in a limit. This situation is an *indeterminate form*.

The format $1^{\infty}$ is another good example of this. In the limit you're looking at, you're right that $1 + x$ goes to $1$ and that $\frac{1}{x}$ goes to $\infty$. But while $1^{\textrm{anything}}$ is certainly $1$, $(\textrm{almost} 1)^{\textrm{big number}}$ is not. To take an extreme example, $0.99^{10000}$ is so close to zero that it has forty zeroes following the decimal point. On the other hand, $0.9999^{100}$ is $0.99$ - nearly one. Because we've got this situation, we can't be sure just by looking which will "win"; the bigness of the exponent or the closeness of the base to $1$. We need to use some more powerful tools, which is what the answers in the question you linked to do.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 
$$ 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e.
$$
But if $a_k\to\infty$, we have $m_k\leq a_k\leq n_k$, hence 
$$ 
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{a_n}\right)^{a_n}=e.
$$
The rest should be easy.